# Calculated Column Duplicate Values

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am fairly new to access. I am trying to create a column that calculates duplicates values in a query. Taking in consideration that the duplicates value may change after other few filters taking action.

```
Supplier    Spec   SupplierDuplicate
   A         X            2
   B         Y            1
   A         Z            2
   C         X            1
```

I most appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean by *the duplicates value may change after other few filters taking action*?

Comment: Edit question to show source data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run a `SELECT` query with `DCount()` function to get expected result.

```
SELECT Table1.Supplier, Table1.Spec, DCount("[Supplier]","[Table1]","[Supplier]='" & Table1.Supplier & "'") AS SupplierDuplicate FROM Table1;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, Thanks fr your response. However, I am getting this error "undefined function dcount in expression" I am using Access 2016.

Comment: Can you show your full expression? `DCount()` is available to all version of access.

Comment: I think the problem that I currently have microsoft office 15.0 access database engine object library, and I need 16.0   SELECT [MCL SQL list].ID, [MCL SQL list].Specification, [MCL SQL list].[Specification Name], [MCL SQL list].Supplier, [MCL SQL list].City, [MCL SQL list].Procedure, [MCL SQL list].StateCountry FROM [MCL SQL list],  DCount("[Supplier]","[MCL SQL list]","[Supplier]='" & [MCL SQL list].Supplier & "'") AS SupplierDuplicate FROM [MCL SQL list];
WHERE ((([MCL SQL list].SupplierDuplicate)=[forms]![Lookup Supplier]![Text42]));